# Relation with condition in laravel

Tags: laravel, model, relation

I have 3 types of author in my app. In table of post author stored in column post_author like "AuthorType_id", where AuthorType can be user, group or system.

The question is: can I create a conditional relation?

What this means.

Relation author() checks a value and return related model.
Data in column stores like "user_123", "system_123", "group_123" where user, system or group is AuthorType and 123 - is id of record in related table.

I'm really confused about this case.
I'm using laravel 6.

Ex:

```
public function author() {
  $type = explode("_", $this->post_author);
  switch($type[0]) {
    case "user":
      return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'id', $type[1]);
    case "group":
      return $this->hasOne('App\UserGroup', 'id', $type[1]);
    default:
      return $this->hasOne('App\BluePoster', 'id', $type[1]);
  }
}
```

Comment: what is this model?

Comment: Laravel morphable?

Comment: I think you need to create the polymorphic relationship

Comment: @TsaiKoga you're mean Custon polymorphic relations? But it's means changing in db structure...

Comment: @TerranceFillip you don't need to changed it. However, if you  change the column name of `AuthorType_id` and `AuthorType` will be good.

Comment: @TsaiKoga no. AuthorType_id - it's description, not name of column. AuthorType = system, group, user, id - means id of record in related table. user_123 means that I need record from user with id 123, system_123 - from blueposters, etc. And this relation stored in column named "post_author"

Comment: @TerranceFillip oh, this means you need to change the structure. And For the old datas, you can create two column, and make a command to split "post_author"'s data into these two column.

Comment: @TsaiKoga and there is no way to use any conditions? I get 400GB db from previous developer with monstrous code and trying to make it more cleaner and readable. Restructuring of db can be problematic on high loaded server.

Comment: @TerranceFillip how many records of this table?

Comment: @TsaiKoga over 2 billion in table of posts, ~10 millions of users, 30 blueposters and ~100k of groups

Comment: It's really huge datas.may be will take u a long times, but I think it will not exceed half hours. However, your table is huge. may be you need to consider about split partition

Comment: @TsaiKoga full refactoring of the code and reorganization of the database is not included in customer's budget :( only adding a new functions. That's why I'm asking about it.